# PHPMailer not working in my cPanel

Tags: php, phpmailer

Here is my code for PHPMailer:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    require '/home/user/public_html/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMPT();
    $mail->Host = 'smpt.gmail.com'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = '*****@gmail.com'; // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'password'; // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587; // TCP port to connect to 587
    $mail->SMPTDebug = 4;
    $mail->setFrom('******@gmail.com', 'Hello whats happening');
    $mail->addAddress('****@gmail.com'); // Add a recipient
    // $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com'); // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('itskosieric@gmail.com');
    //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz'); // Add attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg'); // Optional name
    $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'hi just wanted to say hello';
    $mail->Body = '<p>This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b></p>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
?>
```

It only says "message has been sent" when I comment `$mail->isSMPT();` but doesn't send any E-mail. Please I don't know where this problem is coming from.

Comment: to what address are you sending?

Comment: 'doesn't send', and you 'dont receive', are not the same thing.

Comment: You never set where to send the email to.

Answer (score 1):

SMTP, not SMPT. Apart from that, base your code on examples provided with PHPMailer.

Comment: Thanks  I've realized that i had issues with my spelling.after checking my spelling it return this error                                                                                       2017-06-09 16:16:13 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 2017-06-09 16:16:15 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Network is unreachable)

Comment: Ok, time to read the troubleshooting guide. No point in me repeating what it says here!